# How do networks identify iPhones when their MAC Addresses are constantly changing?

Tags: networking, mac-address

I found out recently that iPhones will change their MAC address every time they connect to a network. But I've found that things like internet filters are still able to identify each unique device, regardless of the device's MAC address, hostname and IP address. How is this possible?

Comment: The internet cannot see your device MAC

Comment: Can you expand on all of these details? What networks? Wifi? Cellular? What internet filters? How do you know that the *device* is identified?

Comment: Various other data that can be used: device name, IMEI, network certificate, fingerprinting the application that is being used, etc.

Comment: Let's not forget the fact that iOS devices cant seem to go even a couple seconds w/o a connection to the mother-ship.

Comment: **User-Agent**. Generally every browser sends a User-Agent identifying the type of device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found out recently that iPhones will change their MAC address *every time they connect to a network.*

The question arises from the italicized part, which isn't quite accurate. iOS devices generate a random MAC address for each Wi-Fi network, however that MAC address is persistent until the network is forgotten.

This prevents having to register a new MAC address to the DHCP server/captive portal every time you connect. If you view a remembered Wi-Fi network in settings, it will list the corresponding MAC address, if you need it for manual registration.

The result is one cannot track *across* networks via the MAC address, but one can track users on the same network.

The [Apple Platform Security guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/wi-fi-privacy-secb9cb3140c/web) states

> In iOS 14 or later, iPadOS 14 or later, and watchOS 7 or later, when an iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or Apple Watch connects to a Wi-Fi network, it identifies itself with a unique (random) MAC address **per network**.

iOS devices use a random MAC address for scanning, but that isn't relevant to a connected network.